# Change UITableView all row's label color on particular row selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I am having a `UILabel` in  `UITableViewCell`. On last row selection I need to change text color of UILabel of all rows. How can i do that?

Comment: use didselectselected row method and just set one index value for select and in cellForRowAtIndexPath check bool true or false and set color or lable

Comment: In didSelectRowAt method check is it last row or not. If its last cell then, then reload the UITableView. And then change the the color of UILabel in all cells in method cellForRowAtIndexPath. Before reloading tableview update the flag to know table was reloaded after tapping on last cell.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Actucally i need the vice versa thing,if user dideselect last row revert back to actual color. now if use didselectselected row method i am changing the bool value and reloading tableview, this is chaning color of all values but .. Now diddeselect is not working.. !!

Comment: tableView.reloadData() did you reload your table in last row didselectselected method

Comment: yes i did it...

Comment: @Niharika check my answer if any problem with mine answer then tell me

Answer (score 1):

```
BOOL *selectlastindex;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    selectlastindex = NO;
    // suggestionList is my NSArray (Data source)
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (selectlastindex == YES) {
        if (indexPath.row == suggestionList.count - 1) {
            suggestiontitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else{
            suggestiontitle.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        }

    }else{
         suggestiontitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"click");

    if (indexPath.row == suggestionList.count - 1) {
        selectlastindex = YES;
        [self.Tableview reloadData];
    }else{
        selectlastindex = NO;
        [self.Tableview reloadData];
    }
}
```

Output : [CHECK OUTPUT](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dtou28zvokvlvup/tableselect.mov?dl=0)

Comment: Thanks.. I will check and let you know. Thanks alot

Comment: @Niharika before impliment check my output that you wnat is perfect or not ?

Comment: Yes . This is same.

Comment: @Niharika are you got answer now ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a boolean like `isLastRowSelected` and set it true if user select the last row and then reload the tableView.
On `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` callback, apply a condition

```
if isLastRowSelected {
    cell.label.textColor = UIColor.desiredColor
}
else {
    cell.label.textColor = UIColor.defaultColor
}
```

Hope it will help:)

Full Explanation:

set a stored property in your class

```
var isLastRowSelected = false
```

then

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // First add the selectedItem in your selectedItems and in the last add this
    isLastRowSelected = selectedItems.count == datasource.count 
     tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if isLastRowSelected {
        cell.label.textColor = UIColor.desiredColor
    }
    else {
        cell.label.textColor = UIColor.defaultColor
    }
}
```

Comment: She wanted to change text color of all rows on last row selection.

Comment: are you trying multiple selection?

Comment: @iProgrammer yes.

Comment: then add just simple logic : if your dataSource count and selectedItems count is same, set isLastRowSelected to true like isLastRowSelected = dataSource.count == selectedItems.count. Let me update

Comment: @iProgrammer Actucally i need the vice versa thing, if user dideselect last row revert back to actual color. now if use didselectselected row method i am changing the bool value and reloading tableview, this is chaning color of all values but .. Now diddeselect is not working.. !!

Comment: Then in didDeselect call back do the same thing. Set your lastRowSelected value in that callback too and reload tableView

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your coloring code in `willDisplayCell:` instead:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// do your logic here:
if (selectlastindex == YES) {
        if (indexPath.row == suggestionList.count - 1) {
            suggestiontitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }else{
            suggestiontitle.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        }

    }else{
         suggestiontitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
}
```